Do I need flashing above the exterior door?
I will be replacing my exterior door and didn’t know if I should be putting in Z flashing above the door frame or not? It is wood siding so not sure how it should be done if so. 

I need to mention, it looks like there is an excessive amount of brick mold edge projecting beyond the siding. Who ever set that door, may have added it, as in not an original install. It appears the rough opening was cut, leaving the siding cut to the rough opening and set the door over the siding. Not a good way to do it. I see no flashing at the door head now, and the way the  the door may be set, it would not be possible to set the flashing the way it is needed, the way Michael Karas has it drawn.

By all means there should be flashing above the door trim at the top. The high side of the flashing should go behind the siding. This Fusion360 sketch I created shows how the flashing would be installed.


Yeah I  am concerned about trying to get it back under the wood siding at this point as well. Seems like a lot easier feat if it was vinyl siding. There are as vinyl up and the previous owners took it off to reveal the wood. Maybe why the molding looks strange as well. If I am not able to, is there a next best alternative or just adding adequate caulking and checking it regularly?

@junta - Getting the flashing up under the siding is easiest if you get it in place before installing the new trim. If there are nails in the way either pull them out it or cut them off behind the siding with an oscillating saw blade that can stand up to cutting metal.

I should have mentioned that my house is older and there is just the wood siding attached without any type of wrapping behind it. If I would slide flashing behind a piece of siding it wouldn't be able to be sealed with tape since the siding is just attached to the framing. How would this impact the decision to add a drip cap?

@junta - It still provides benefit in that any water that sneaks in under the siding gets confined there instead of being able to leak further into the framing and wall structure.
